# Should I use pk or a unique slug in my url?

Tags: python, django, url-routing, django-urls

I want to write the URLconf for a shopping cart app I wrote in django. I wonder what is the preferred way of constructing URLs.

The URL is accessible by the users via a hyperlink(They are not supposed to type it in the address bar). It adds the specified item to their shopping cart. should I

use the pk for the item:

```
http://example.com/add/253
```

or use a unique slug:

```
http://example.com/add/unique_item_slug
```

Do any of these approaches have security or performance advantage. Is there any reason to prefer one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason for using slugs is SEO (Search, Engine Optimisation). The argument is that 
a search for 'My awesome widget' will return results which place -

```
http://example.com/products/my_awesome_widget
```

higher than

```
http://example.com/products/423
```

Google likes URL's that make sense to human beings. Ideally you want the URL to say as much about the page as possible. Have a look at the section 'Improve the Structure of your URLs' in [googles SEO starter guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.co.uk/en/uk/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf).

Since you're going to be selling things online, it's going to be important that web surfers easily find your products on search engines. Therefor the use of slugs is definitely recommended.

One disadvantage in depending solely on slugs is that you'll need to coerce the product name into an **unique** slug. You probably don't currently have a unique constraint on the product name, so you may have to do a bit of work creating the slug (by checking for whether the slug you're about to create already exists). A common solution is to include the slug and the product id.

```
http://example.com/products/my-awesome-widget/243
```

That way your slug doesn't have to be unique, but your url still includes the product name.

Answer (score 0):

Over the modern web development, you can do use your pk in the URL and that wouldn't be a problem.

Relying in a pretty restful design I would recomend you:

```
http://example.com/product/253/add
```

where the `http://example.com/product/253` is your product detailed view.

Answer (score 0):

As Ewen said, the point of putting titles directly in the URL is SEO. Having keywords in the URL has a significant effect on search engine results

There isn't really any significant security risk with using the primary key in the URL, other than the ability for people to guess/predict other ones. But you shouldn't be relying on

> nobody will guess this

as a security measure anyway.